# Using date to find last monday in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a very simple query

```
SELECT SUM(Balance) FROM TimeSystem
WHERE EmployeeNo = @EmployeeNo
AND RegDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND EndDate
```

Now I've been given the assignment to create a query that returns the balance, but only from monday of the same week as @EndDate.

So I need to create a variable that uses @EndDate and finds the date of monday that same week and then places it in a variable called @Monday for instance.

I've only worked with SQL about 3 months so I'm not sure if this is archieveable?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @date datetime
set @date=GETDATE()

select DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0,@date),0)
```

Comment: Your suggestion returns **2012-12-31 00:00:00.000** which is a monday, but not in the current week.

Comment: just edited it, it will return date of monday of the current week

Comment: This depends on `SET DATEFIRST` setting.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for Sundays. On a Sunday it will quote the Monday afterwards

Comment: What is the solution to not get the next Monday on a Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate version that will, on Sundays, get the prior Monday:

```
DECLARE @date DATE

SET @date = '2017-06-18' -- GETDATE()

SELECT DATEADD(DAY
                 ,CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date)WHEN 1 THEN -6 ELSE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date) - 2) * -1 END
                 ,@date
              )
```